# The C++ Template function call isn't in scope

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to study C++ template relative things, and I encountered one problem, the source code is as below, I have tried every method possible, but it didn't work, could someone can help? thanks!!

```
template<typename T>
class myTest{
 public:
  bool (T::*funcInTemplate)() const;
  void addFunc(bool (T::*myFunc)() const = nullptr) {
    funcInTemplate = myFunc;
  }
};

class test : public myTest<test> {
 public:
  test() {
    addFunc(&test::func1);
  }
  bool func1() const {
    return true;
  }
};


int main(void) {

  test t;
  bool b = /* **Question is here, how to call "funcInTemplate" through instance t?** */;
  std::cout << "ret is " << b << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I have tried **t.funcInTemplate** method, the compiler tell me **"error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function"**

I have tried **t.*funcInTemplate** method, the compiler tell me **"error: ‘funcInTemplate’ was not declared in this scope"**

Answers like using dot operator method may solve a half of this problem but not the whole.

Comment: call it using dot operator like this `t.func1()`

Comment: I think there is something easy for careless, I have modified it. the function I want to call is "funcInTemplate" NOT "func1". Do you know how to call "funcInTemplate" through instance t?

Answer (score 2):

Do it like:

```
  test t;
  bool b = t.func1();
  std::cout << "ret is " << b << std::endl;
```

You should call a class method using the class object followed by dot operator.

Comment: @nwp I already did that. It is returning the proper value. Either 1 or 0, for true and false.

Comment: You were supposed to call `func`, not `func1`.

Comment: I have modified a bit the description of my concern, that I want to call function "funcInTemplate" through instance t, do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the dot operator on the test object like t.func1(). You can also create a pointer if you prefer like test *t = new test; Then just call using t->func1()